# Stop/Start AsyncTask Thread and Stop/Start UIThread in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

Yesterday i have asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33387328/textview-doesnt-synchronize?answertab=active#tab-top), here can see what app i'm building and how it works. Yet i would that when the CPU attemp a number the AsyncTask thred is stopped and is started the UIThread in a specific method. Example: After that the CPU say a number he waith so that i have sayd one. Such like turn based.First CPU than i, than again the CPU than again me. So i sholud stop the thread of AsyncTask when te CPU say his number and start the UIThread that allow to work the number that i say, than stop the UIThread and start again the AsyncThread. How can i do this?

P.S Sorry for the bad english

Comment: I don't have idea how i should this..

Comment: I know that i should work on threads, but don't should how.. wait() is for thread that work in the same monitor, and stop is deprecated.. what should i use?

Comment: I do not know if I understood you correctly, but there a number of ways to solve problems. For your specific case I do not think you need a thread running all the time. You can execute asynctasks when needed. If the task you are running (_CPU say a number_) are fast, you do not even need a Thread. Try to do a minimal running example and then come back to get specific help because without that will be hard to you get any help.

Comment: Ok i undestand, I try it!